# FTP file download order with Spring integration

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

I am using spring integration for downloading a set of PDF and XML files from an SFTP server. The process is triggered by a poller based on cron. I need to make sure that all the XML files are downloaded completely before the PDF files from the same remote directory. 
I don't want to use two different cron jobs to trigger these. 
How can I solve this? Thanks in advance. (NOTE: I am new to the integration framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom `FileListFilter` in the `filter` attribute (use `FTPFile` for FTP and `LsEntry` for SFTP as the parameterized generic type).

In the `filterFiles` method, sort the candidate file list into the order in which you want them downloaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot @garry your solution worked to sort the files before importing from SFTP. But after importing I am triggering spring batch jobs for each of the files. Since batch jobs are executed by a pool of executors in parallel, the order does not seems to be maintained. When I reduce the number of executors to 1, the order is retained though.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean; if you don't release the PDF until the corresponding XML completely arrives, what difference does the processing order make?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I checked my code and it looks like the sorted order is not maintained after passing to the channel from SFTP. I have pasted the main parts of the code in the description. Could you please point out what is wrong here?

Comment: Ah, yes; there's a local filter too (which you have). The synchronizer filter controls the download order but the files might be found on the local disk in a different order. You need to customize the local filter to sort as well.

Comment: I customised the local filter also but still the output shows a different order. When I am debugging the filter seems to be working fine (it sorts as expected), but the order changes afterwards. By the way can I use a `resequencer` somehow to retain the sort order? if so could you provide some links to try it out?

Comment: That makes no sense; if they are sorted by the filter, that's the order the messages will be emitted. Of course, since you then hand off the message to a thread pool like you do in `downloadChannel`, any ordering will be lost. If you need strict ordering, you need to use a single thread.

Comment: Got it @Gary.. Yes it's logical. When I am limiting the number of threads to maintain the order,  it's working as expected. Thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to count number of files in the directory, then use this in a loop. To check on number of files on UNIX system, you can use following command:

```
ls -1fa | wc -l
```

After downloading all XMLs, you can trigger another method that will start downloading the PDF files.